# searching filtering comprehension in package table in Packages Menu

Tags: package

How can one search a specific name or a pattern for the name of a specific package on the package menu returned from `M-x list-packages`?

In documentation it says type `f`. but in my case it yields an empty table list of packages.

Same question generally for filtering this table based on package name, keywords, version(equality,  and optional inequality expressions) , status, archive, namely the column names.

Comment: What about `C-s`?

Comment: :) nice. But wanna filter the table of the packages. Only see the related packages, based on name or keyword pattern match.

Comment: A post about packages [filtering](http://endlessparentheses.com/new-in-emacs-25-1-filtering-by-status-and-archive.html?source=rss)

Answer (score 1):

**`f`** works for me.  Does it not work for you even if you start Emacs without your init file (i.e., `emacs -Q`)?

If that works for you, then recursively bisect your init file to find out what is interfering.  You can use command `comment-region` to comment out a region of text (`C-u` with the command uncomments the region). Comment out 1/2, then 3/4, 7/8, 15/16, 31/32,... - it is very quick to do (binary search).